# Emacs Subsequence Autocomplete

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete

I have successfully set up jedi to do standard auto complete. However, it only matches letters at the start of the word. If there is a method called `toBankCurrency`, then typing `tob` pops it up just fine.

I would like the option to type `tbc` and have `toBankCurrency` pop up. I've seen this described as subsequence matching, fuzzy matching, and camel-hump matching.

Is this possible in Emacs? [This Github request](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/47) implies that ELisp is too slow. There is a [possible solution here](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/47#issuecomment-33472005), but it involves explicitly calling the autcomplete (I would prefer to have it pop up automatically) and is described as being slow.

My main priority is setting this up with the Python language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native completion style in Emacs (which company can/does use) includes `partial-completion` which does what you want when the words are separated by things like `-` or `_`.

The exact description of the separators is controlled by `completion-pcm--delim-wild-regex` which can hande "0-width" separators such as the one of camel-case.  This is currently only used when you do `C-x REF f` so you can hit `u8 TAB` to complete to `utf-8`, but it should be easy to set it so it completes `eR` or `emR` to `emacsRules`.

For the expansion of `er` to `emacsRules`, you'd probably need to use something different: either something like the `initials` completion style, or some kind of "flex" matching method.

I'd welcome patches to add those functionalities to Emacs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Looks I have a lot of research to do.